# CSS not selector with after content

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Is it possible to use the :not() selector/pseudo thing with :after?

So for example if I have the following:

```
li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

li:after
{
    content: " ";
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #cccccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
}
```

What happens is that if a person HOVERS over the content that is created by the after it will also make the child menu display block. In other words hovering other the LI or the AFTER content is acknowledged as hovering the LI. How would I stop this, so it only does the display block when hovering the ACTUAL LI and NOT the content created using AFTER.

I thought about: `li:hover:not(:after) > ul { display: none; }` but hasn't worked...

Also tried: `li:after:hover > ul` but also didn't work.

Any ideas for this? It might seem trivial but it's causes some issues in my design so need to stop it doing it asap.

Comment: Can you give some example HTML? I can't quite wrap my head around what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

As you observe, `:hover` styles on an element will be triggered when hovering over its contents, including descendants and pseudo-elements. However, you can't prevent `:hover` styles on an element from applying to its `:after` pseudo-element, nor can you use `:not()` to select `:after` pseudo-elements (this is explicitly disallowed by the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation)).

This is by design, so the only way around it is to not use `:after`, but use JavaScript to generate some other element that you can append to the `li` and cancel the `:hover` effect on.

Comment: Tried using JS: `$('li:after').hover(function() { $(this).find('ul').css({'display':'none'}); });` but hasn't worked either...

Comment: @Cameron: You can't use JS to insert `:after` content. You need to insert an entirely new element, like a `span`, so `$('li').append('span').hover(...);`

Comment: Still doesn't work as the hover of the span is classed as hovering the li it has been appended to! So I have to override EVERYTHING which is impossible and not ideal!

Answer (score 1):

Actualiy it is possible with the use of the attribute "pointer-events" and assign it to none in the pseudo-element :after or :before .

So it would be -> pointer-events: none; in the pseudo-element.